# Python dict grouping

Tags: python

I am trying to develop a code that groups the dict, the code works alone but I want to make it as a function; and I want to add a code to check the duplicates and just print one of them.

```
a_dict = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}


def fun_dict():
    b_dict = {}
    for i, v in a_dict.items():
        b_dict[v] = [i] if v not in b_dict.keys() else b_dict[v] + [i]



b_dict = fun_dict(a_dict)
print(b_dict)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xxx.py", line 11, in <module>
    b_dict = fun_dict(a_dict)
TypeError: fun_dict() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: Should be: `def fun_dict(a_dict):`, if you pass an argument to a function the function should take it.

Comment: Per default all functions return `None`, you need to return `b_dict` within the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the function accepting the argument as well as returning `b_dict`:

```
a_dict = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}


def fun_dict(a_dict):
    b_dict = {}
    for i, v in a_dict.items():
        b_dict[v] = [i] if v not in b_dict.keys() else b_dict[v] + [i]
    return b_dict


b_dict = fun_dict(a_dict)
print(b_dict)
```

Out:

```
{1: ['A'], 2: ['B'], 3: ['C']}
```

Comment: Thank you, now it works. How can I check the duplicated items.

Comment: What you mean by _duplicated items_ ?

Comment: @programminglearner: You cant have duplicates in a dict, so the last value of duplicate key is 'winning'/overwriting the previous value.

Comment: What do you mean by _expand_ ?

Comment: Please ask a new question, that shouldn't be covered in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You did not define a parameter for your method, and you are trying to send one. Thats why you are getting an error.

Your a_dict variable is a global variable, you dont have to send it as a parameter.

Your b_dict variable is defined in your fun_dict function, and you can not print it outside of your function